# Documentation of 不+"x" contractions resulting in "r" sounding initial consonant?

Tags: pronunciation

I've been looking for documentation showing 不+"x" contractions resulting in "r" sounding initial consonants, but to no avail.

This is an interesting phenomenon and I'm sure the regular person would say: "*it's just people talking fast, don't over think it,*" but in technical terms these would be some form of contractions. Think:

- 不 + 知道 = bu rao
- 不 + 是 = bu ri

I'm interested to know what kind of research has been done on these contractions, if any.

Any ideas?

Comment: It’s worth noting that 是, 知, and Pinyin [r] are all [retroflex consonants](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroflex_consonant). I don’t think quite the same effect can be achieved with, say, 不好.

Comment: Something to do with [ɿ] perhaps?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, no, I don’t think it has something to do with [ɿ]. Consider 不少, I can imagine it being pronounced as **burao**, but [ɿ] doesn’t appear in the words.

Comment: This just exits in accent of Beijing (or places around Beijing), not in Madarin.

Comment: 不知道 sometimes reads **bu ri dao**, even **bu rao**, as well as that 告诉你 reads as **gaor ni**, and 就这样 reads as **jiu zhang**.

Comment: @賈可Jacky The contraction of 这样 should be written: "掌," if I'm not mistaken, i.e.: 就掌. While **gaor ni** is written 告儿你. These have some sort of documentation, I believe. But, I've struggled to find much about 不知道 contractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This phenomenon is a non-standard regional accent, known as [儿化音](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%92%E5%8C%96%E9%9F%B3). It is a phenomenon in some part of North China, especially in Beijing.

> 不知道 (bù zhī dào) → 不<sub>儿</sub>道 (bùr rào)
>
> 不是 (bù shì) → bú shì → 不<sub>儿</sub> (búr)
>
> 告诉你 (gào sù nǐ) → 告<sub>儿</sub>你 (gàor nǐ)